# Unzipping appearing to fail

Tags: ubuntu, backup, gzip

I run:

```
~$ gzip -d Mom.img.gz
^C
~$
```

I created `Mom.img.gz` by piping a `dd` to `gzip`. Should I be seeing output? I tried it with the GUI too, and the progress bar didn't move.

Answer (score 3):

No you'll typically see no output from `gzip` when you use it to compress or uncompress.

#### Examples

Say I have a sample file.

```
$ ll | grep a.img
-rw-rw-r--.   1 saml saml   1474560 Mar 31 21:57 a.img
```

*compressing*

```
$ gzip a.img 
$
$ ll | grep a.img
-rw-rw-r--.   1 saml saml    944497 Mar 31 21:57 a.img.gz
```

*uncompressing*

```
$ gzip -d a.img.gz 
$
$ ll | grep a.img
-rw-rw-r--.   1 saml saml   1474560 Mar 31 21:57 a.img
```

If you'd like a little more feedback while `gzip` is doing its thing you can include the `--verbose` or `-v` switch to get a bit more output.

```
$ gzip -vd a.img.gz 
a.img.gz:    35.9% -- replaced with a.img
```

#### Why no feedback?

If you think that `gzip` isn't working, it's likely that it is, and it's actually running just fine. You can watch the process to confirm that it's actually doing something useful by opening another shell and running a command such as `top` or `htop` to see what the `gzip` process is doing as it runs.

Also you can use a command such as this to "watch" it.

```
$ watch "ps -eaf | grep [g]zip"
```

You can also use the command line tool `pidstat` to "watch" processes:

```
$ pidstat -r 2 -C thunder
Linux 3.13.6-100.fc19.x86_64 (greeneggs.bubba.net)  03/31/2014  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

10:26:24 PM   UID       PID  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ    RSS   %MEM  Command
10:26:26 PM  1000      3323     24.38      0.00 1572252 323264   4.06  thunderbird

10:26:26 PM   UID       PID  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ    RSS   %MEM  Command
10:26:28 PM  1000      3323    138.50      0.00 1572252 322720   4.05  thunderbird
```

Above I'm watching my mail client, `thunderbird` displaying a summary of CPU load every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pv`, the "pipe viewer", to monitor how much and how fast data is processed and/or output by a process.
<sub>On Debian/Ubuntu, you will need to install the [package `pv`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pv) to use it.</sub>

```
pv a.img.gz | gzip -cd > a.img
```

will give you a the total and current throughput of `gzip`, as well as a progress bar and estimate when `gzip` will finish processing the input file (assuming its speed will stay the same).

You can also monitor the output…

```
gzip -cd a.img.gz | pv > a.img
```

… or even combine the two command and monitor input and output at the same time:

```
pv -cN input a.img.gz | gzip -cd | pv -cN output > a.img
```

(In this case, you need `pv`'s `-c` option to prevent the two progress indicators from overwriting each other, and `-N` to give them (arbitrary) names to know which is which.)